# Rest Assured only GET Api calls are failing with 404 but post, put etc are working fine

Tags: rest, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, rest-assured

All GET Api calls are failing with 404 but post, put etc are working fine with Rest assured

We are using RestAssured for rest layer testing. All get apis are failing with :-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

But all post, delete, put etc APIs are working fine.
Below is the code for get which is not working :-

```
RestAssured.given().
            header("Authorization","someToken").
            when().
                get(BASE_URI + "location/listAll").
            then().
            statusCode(200);
            }catch (Exception numberFormatException) {
                numberFormatException.getMessage();
            }
```

Below is code for post which is working :-

```
RestAssured.given().log().all().header("Authorization","someToken")
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
body(LocationModel).
            when().
                post(BASE_URI + "location/create").
            then().
            statusCode(200);
            }catch (Exception numberFormatException) {
                numberFormatException.getMessage();
            }
```

Comment: 404 means you url not found. verify if you define well your url ( maybee you forget a trailing slash or something else ). I can help you more if I not have you routes configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Same get url is working fine with postman/UI but failing on test case. And as mentioned only all the GET APIs are failing.

Comment: I don't see media type / content type in your GET statement like the one available with POST statement. Maybe that will be the problem.